# how to add dropdown list in detailview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox

I am trying to access the values in the drop down list from the code behind but I am getting this error:  “ddl_Ext does not exist in the current context”.   I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.. can someone please help?  Here is my drop-down list in aspx file. Thanks.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is this external?">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblExt" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Ext") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Ext" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Please select ..." Value="Please Select ..."></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>

          </asp:DropDownList>
          </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is the code behind i am trying to use:

```
protected void DV_WScript_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
      string Ext = ddl_Ext.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: From where in the codebehind do you try to access it ?

Comment: You need to find control and cast it `DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("ddlName");`

Comment: That's because it's inside the `EditItemTemplate` of the `TemplateField`. You'll need to access it via the `Rows[{index}].FindControl("ddl_Ext")`.

Comment: thanks guys i have just updted my initial post adding the code behind i was trying to use

Comment: thank The-Val, it seems your solution to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
protected void DV_WScript_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
        //Put here if you want to find control of your Insert Mode
           DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("ddl_Ext");
           string Ext = dropDown.selectedValue;

}
```